# How to get first child with specify element in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML..

```
<div class = "thumbnail">
  <img src = "somePath">
</div>
 <div class = "thumbnail">
  <img src = "somePath">
</div>
<div class = "thumbnail">
  <img src = "somePath">
</div>
<div class = "thumbnail">
  <a href = "someLink"><img src = "somePath"></a>
</div>
<div class = "thumbnail">
  <a href = "someLink"><img src = "somePath"></a>
</div>
```

I want to iterate **img** tags under the first child of **div.thumbnail**. I want to filter them out.
I use as..

```
var i =0;
$("div.thumbnail :first-child").each(function() {
    console.log("Touch "+(++i)+" time(s) !");
    if($(this).context.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        console.log("Getting Image Tag.");
    }
});
```

My question is I want to filter in getting elements ..

```
$("div.thumbnail :first-child :img").each(function(){});
```

I don't want to iterate as count of **div.thumbnail** . I want to iterate as count of **div.thumbnail** with first child tag is **img**.  How to figure it out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
$(".thumbnail > img").each(function(){
    //
});
```

This will skip the following divs where first child is not an `img`

```
<div class = "thumbnail">
  <a href = "someLink"><img src = "somePath"></a>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rVJyd/)

Comment: He's trying to get the parents not the children

Comment: I'm just saying you asked in the Original Post how to iterate the **parents**, and this code is iterating the children.

Comment: @Itay , Thanks for guiding me. And I asked I want to iterate img tags.

Comment: According to the parents... You said it specifically

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`:has() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$("div.thumbnail:has( > img:first-child)").each(function(){});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/fQEbD/1/)

Comment: I also got with your answer ! Cheer .. :) now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".thumbnail:has('> img:first-child'),.thumbnail > img:first-child").each(function(){
     //TO Do here
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rickyjecobs/2ksFB/)